# Failed to put two functions in one graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was trying to put two plots of different functions in one graph, but the second one didn't show up in the graph. Does somebody see the mistake? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FunctionA}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{300 + 1000/x + 2.5*x}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FunctionB}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{290 + 1000/x + 2.45*x}%
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, thick, samples=400}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=750,
    ymin=300, ymax=600,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    xlabel= $y$
    ylabel=Cost,]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=black, domain=0:250] (\x,{FunctionA(\x)});
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=black, domain=250:500] (\x,{FunctionB(\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
```

Comment: Remove `ymin=300, ymax=600,`.

Comment: @Jake -- I understand your view, but my view is that the OP does not know how to plot two functions on the same plots. After all, this is one application taught in pgfplots. See page 132 of the manual. Anyway, I will let the community to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since two functions are plotted and they have different ranges,  this calls for two (y axis) ordinates plotting skill.

The idea is to draw two axes on top of each others. One on the left, one on the right. The key is to put `scale only axis` in each axis, and same extended domain for x axis.

`axis y discontinuity` is also used here for better presentation of plots.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FunctionA}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{300 + 1000/x + 2.5*x}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FunctionB}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{290 + 1000/x + 2.45*x}%
}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, thick, samples=400}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.53,0.50)}, anchor=north west},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=750,
    ymin=200,
    axis y discontinuity=parallel,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    xlabel= $y$,
    ylabel=Cost,]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=black, domain=0:250] (\x,{FunctionA(\x)});
\legend{Function A}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.53,0.60)}, anchor=north west},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=750,
    ymin=800,
    axis y  discontinuity=parallel,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=right, 
    xlabel= $y$,
    ylabel=Cost]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=red, domain=250:500] (\x,{FunctionB(\x)});
\legend{Function B}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The axis discontinuity symbols are misleading in this case, since they suggest that there is a discontinuity between 200 and 400 on the left y axis and between 800 and 900 on the right y axis. Also, when plotting two `axis` environments on top of each other, one should take care not to print things twice: In this case, one of the `axis` environments should use `hide x axis`, otherwise the x axis labels show up too bold in some viewers.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Agree 100%. No need for discontinuity command. Here I see an application of the discontinuity skill to see plots more clearly than otherwise.